# ¿Cómo redireccionar web http a https?

Tags: dominio, virtualhost, redirección

Tengo el siguiente código de un VirtualHost (el mismo que tengo en otro dropet con otro dominio y funciona) no sé si sea por el dominio regional:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName dominio.com.ar
  ServerAlias www.dominio.com.ar
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio/public
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dominio.com.ar [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dominio.com.ar
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Pero no hace la redirección

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Agrego esas líneas y dejo el resto?

Answer (score 0):

- Lo mejor es que hagas la redirección a través de .htaccess y elimines
  las entradas del virtualhost con el que estás trabajando.
- Entiendo de que tienes un certificado instalado para esa web y
  añadidas las directivas para activar SSL y apuntar a la ruta del certificado (SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile, etc) en un virtualhost donde escucha en el puerto 443 (https).

En ese caso, en la carpeta a la que está apuntando el DocumentRoot (/var/www/dominio/public), añade un fichero .htaccess con las siguientes directivas:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

De esta forma rediriges todas las peticiones que se hagan `(.*)` hacia el mismo dominio con la misma URL pero cambiando el puerto a https.

Comment: Gracias, una de las dos, correcto? me iría por la segunda

Comment: Serían ambos puntos, Joseph. Puedes redirigir a https pero si no tienes un virtualhost configurado escuchando en el puerto 443 (por ejemplo: <VirtualHost *:43>) con las directivas de SSL apuntando al certificado configurado, al cargar la web redirigida a https te dará error de seguridad aunque te permita el acceso de modo inseguro. Luego, sería añadir el fichero .htaccess con ese contenido en la carpeta que es accesible de forma pública (public).

Comment: okey, estoy trabajando con Laravel y tengo un .htacces, solo cambio esas línea?